# How to create separate thread pool that uses master thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, concurrency, threadpool

I'm using `spring` `ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean`. Its a master thread pool. And for some cases I need to create `CompletionService` it ensures that I got threads in its completion order.

My code snippet:

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(list.size());

CompletionService<T> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<T>(pool);
```

Problem is i don't want to create fixed thread pool here but use master thread poll, just to avoid too many threads creation.

I cannot pass master thread pool to completion service of course, cause when i take value from completion service `completionService.take()` i would get completely non related threads.

Maybe you can help me to find a way how to create some kind of fixed thread pool from master thread pool and pass it to completion service.

Many thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to make a custom `ExecutorService` that has one pool of threads, and different queues for different classes of task.  It need not be a fully custom object, it might just be a wrapper that layers some extra smarts on top of ThreadPoolExecutor.

Answer (score 0):

There is a misunderstanding here. A `CompletionService` simply receives tasks, executes them asynchronously and makes the result available in the order the tasks completes. `CompletionService#take()` returns the result of a submitted task, not a thread.

An `ExecutorCompletionService` delegates the task execution to an `Executor` which may very well execute tasks submitted from another source. So there should be no problem doing what your code example shows.